# Can .aspx , .ascx works with .net 8

Tags: webforms, devexpress, .net-8.0, .net-4.7.2

I am trying to migrate from . Net 4.7.2 to . Net 8. The thing is that am using webform with dev Express, customcontrol .ascx and .aspx extension can these extensions works with .net 8

Comment: .NET 8 is .NET *Core* 8 and WebForms was never migrated to .NET Core nor will they ever be. The demand isn't there. WebForms were replaced by MVC over 10 years ago, long before .NET Core 1.0. They were simply too different to the way web apps and HTTP work so developers either abandoned .NET entirely before MVC, or moved to MVC as quickly as possible once it came out

Comment: Check the migration guide at [Upgrade an ASP.NET Framework Web Forms app to ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/web_forms?view=aspnetcore-8.0). There's no automatic migration path though. You can't just jump 13 years forward in web tech without *significant* rewriting. If your company delayed the migration to MVC to avoid rewrites, they'll have to do even more work now. On the plus side, you'll be able to deploy to far cheaper Linux machines and use Docker containers, something impossible with .NET Framework

Comment: Not much to add to the great comments above. If the webforms application was converted to MVC, and .net framework, then a migration to .net core MVC would be VERY easy, and very minor. However, a migration from webforms to MVC (.net core, or .net framework) is much the same issue - it is a re-write of the webforms application. Thus asmx web methods, or user controls etc. can't be used in these newer projects. So, DevExpress does have versions of their controls and objects that work with MVC, and they also now have .net core versions. But, existing web forms devExpress controls can't be used.